# How to combine two stacked bar charts onto the same axis

Tags: graph, stata

I have been tasked to make a figure with two stacked bar charts on the same axis.

While this is generally easy enough, I have run into trouble since the two bar charts do not have a set of common values (like year for instance) that they share in common.

The dataset I am using can be found below:

```
clear 
input str42 outcomes perct str42 highcred hperct 
"Certificate & Diploma Only"  8.33    "Certificate & Diploma"   8.33
"Associate Only"              2.93    "Associate"               14.29
"Bachelor Only"               11.36   "Bachelor"                6.93
"Certificate + AA"            2.2     "" .
"Associate + Bachelor"        4.33    "" . 
end
```

My code is the following:

```
*B. Create a seperate variable for each value of outcomes
    levelsof outcomes, local(out)
    tokenize "1 2 3 4 5"
    foreach level of local out {
        gen outcome`1' = .
        replace outcome`1' = perct if outcomes=="`level'"
        mac shift
        }

*C. Create a seperate variable for each value of highgred
    levelsof highcred, local(high)
    tokenize "1 2 3"
    foreach level of local high {
        gen highcred`1' = .
        replace highcred`1' = hperct if highcred=="`level'"
        mac shift
        }   

//2: Create Bar graphs

    *A. Bar 1
        graph bar outcome1-outcome5, stack saving(bar1) 

    *B. Bar 2 
        graph bar highcred1-highcred3, stack saving(bar2)

    *C. Combine graphs
        graph combine bar1.gph bar2.gph, ycommon
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ycommon` option works as intended. However, your solution for stacking the bars in separate graphs and then combining them is problematic in the sense that the two graphs share the same colors, which makes it impossible to distinguish the different categories. An additional challenge is how these categories can be incorporated in a single legend.

Below you can find a solution that addresses both of these problems:

```
levelsof outcomes, local(out)
levelsof highcred, local(high)
local highcopy "`high'"

local c1: word count `out'
local c2: word count `high'

local colors1 ebblue pink brown
local colors2 `colors1'

forvalues i = 1 / `= `c1' + `c2'' {
    generate outcome`i' = .
    gettoken outc out : out
    if `i' <= `c1' replace outcome`i' = perct if outcomes == "`outc'" 
    if `i' > `c1' {
        gettoken color colors1 : colors1
        local bars1 `bars1' bar(`i', color(`color'))
    }
    if `i' <= `c2' {
        generate highcred`i' = .
        gettoken highcc highcopy : highcopy
        replace highcred`i' = hperct if highcred == "`highcc'"
        gettoken color colors2 : colors2
        local bars2 `bars2' bar(`i', color(`color')) 
    } 
    if `i' <= `c1' local legend `legend' label(`i' "`outc'")
    else {
        gettoken highc high : high
        local legend `legend' label(`i' "`highc'")
    }
}

order outcome* high*

graph bar outcome1-outcome8, stack ///
                             ylabel(, nogrid) ///
                             graphregion(color(white)) ///
                             `bars1' ///
                             name(bar1, replace) ///
                             legend(`legend')

graph bar highcred1-highcred3, stack ///
                               ylabel(, nogrid) ///
                               yscale(off) ///
                               graphregion(color(white)) ///
                               `bars2' ///
                               name(bar2, replace) 

grc1leg bar1 bar2, ycommon graphregion(color(white)) legendfrom(bar1)
```

[image]

Adding the option `blabel(bar, position(base))` in each `graph bar` command will produce:

[image]

Note that the *community-contributed* command `grc1leg` is used to create the combined graph.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the data. I guess that the order of values is worth preserving, although I don't think your code does that. I suggest that you will be much, much better off with a different data structure, horizontal bars and no stacking. `graph bar (asis)` is a better idea to avoid nonsense about means in the legend if you have a legend, but you don't need a legend at all.

For this, you would need to install `labmask` from the *Stata Journal* (`search labmask` to get a link).

You should be able to use better text than `outcomes highcred`.

```
clear 
input str42 outcomes perct str42 highcred hperct 
"Certificate & Diploma Only"  8.33    "Certificate & Diploma"   8.33
"Associate Only"              2.93    "Associate"               14.29
"Bachelor Only"               11.36   "Bachelor"                6.93
"Certificate + AA"            2.2     "" .
"Associate + Bachelor"        4.33    "" . 
end 

rename (outcomes-hperct) (x1 p1 x2 p2) 
gen id = _n 
reshape long x p , i(id) j(which) 

sort which id
replace id = _n
drop in 9/10 
labmask id, values(x)
label def which 1 "outcomes" 2 "highcred"
label val which which

graph hbar (asis) p, over(id) over(which) nofill scheme(s1color) ytitle(percent) ///
bar(1, bfcolor(none)) blabel(total, pos(base) format(%3.2f)) yla(none) ysc(alt)
```

[image]